# Robust estimation of Poisson distribution

Tags: r, estimation, poisson-distribution, generalized-linear-model, robust

I have a set of numbers which are assumed to be coming from a Poisson distribution. The set has some outliers also and because of that, maximum likelihood estimates are badly affected. I heard that robust estimation procedures can help in such a situation. Can any one explain how to do this? I am not a statistics student.

I found that the `glmrob` function in R can be used for this. (I am quite new to R). But I could not figure out, how to use that despite reading the manual pages. In particular I am unable to understand how to get a `forumula` which is the first argument to the glmrob function.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the glmrob [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robust/robust.pdf)?  There is sample code for a robust Poisson fit at p. 23.

Comment: I did look at them. In that example in page 23, there is a formula like this `sumY ~ Age10 + Base4*Trt`. With the data I have, I am unable to come up with any such formulae. I just have a bunch of numbers assumed to be coming from a Poisson distribution. As I understand, I do not have a dependent variable and independent variable and may be that is why I am unable to come up with a formula.

Comment: You implicitly have an intercept term.

Comment: @cardinal could  you kindly explain what you meant by `You implicitly have an intercept term`

Comment: You have poisson counts that are your responses and your "predictors" consist of just an intercept term, i.e., you want to model it as if all of your responses come from the same distribution. Does that make more sense? :)

Comment: @cardinal can you give an example of the `formula` for the first argument of `glmrob` the way you describe?. The arguments to glmrob are `glmRob(formula, family, data, weights, subset,....)`

Comment: Example formula: `y~1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@cardinal has telegraphed an answer in comments.  Let's flesh it out.  His point is that although general linear models (such as implemented by `lm` and, in this case, `glmRob`) appear intended to evaluate relationships among variables, they can be powerful tools for studying a single variable, too.  The trick relies on the fact that **regressing data against a *constant* is just another way of estimating its average value ("location")**.

As an example, generate some Poisson-distributed data:

```
set.seed(17)
x <- rpois(10, lambda=2)
```

In this case, `R` will produce the vector $(1,5,2,3,2,2,1,1,3,1)$ of values for `x` from a Poisson distribution of mean $2$.  Estimate its location with `glmRob`:

```
library(robust)
glmrob(x ~ 1, family=poisson())
```

The response tells us the *intercept* is estimated at $0.7268$.  Of course, anyone using a statistical method needs to know how it works: when you use generalized linear models with the Poisson family, the standard "link" function is the logarithm.  This means the intercept is the *logarithm* of the estimated location.  So we compute

```
exp(0.7268)
```

The result, $2.0685$, is comfortably close to $2$: the procedure seems to work.  To *see* what it is doing, plot the data:

```
plot(x, ylim=c(0, max(x)))
abline(exp(0.7268), 0, col="red")
```

[image: Plot with fitted line]

The fitted line is purely horizontal and therefore estimates the middle of the vertical values: our data.  That's all that's going on.

To check robustness, let's create a bad outlier by tacking a few zeros onto the first value of `x`:

```
x[1] <- 100
```

This time, for greater flexibility in post-processing, we will save the output of `glmRob`:

```
m <- glmrob(x ~ 1, family=poisson())
```

To obtain the estimated average we can request

```
exp(m$coefficients)
```

The value this time equals $2.496$: a little off, but not too far off, given that the average value of `x` (obtained as `mean(x)`) is $12$.  That is the sense in which this procedure is "robust."  More information can be obtained via

```
summary(m)
```

Its output shows us, among other things, that the weight associated with the outlying value of $100$ in `x[1]` is just $0.02179$, almost $0$, pinpointing the suspected outlier.

Comment: (+1) Nice presentation, as usual. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such an answer is very important for me now because I am completely new to all this (terms like predictor, intercept, and even the package R).

Comment: Can you point to a similar tool for a bivariate Poisson distribution?

Comment: @Diogo It depends on what that tool is intended to do and precisely what form of dependence among the marginals is being used.